# Not able to include child model inside parent model through findAll query in sequelize Next.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, next.js, sequelize.js

I am not able to get child table data in my parent data associated below is my code.

**Here is my Role Model Schema**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Role extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.hasMany(models.User, {
        as: "users",
        foreignKey: "roleId",
        onDelete: "SET NULL",
      });
    }
  }
  Role.init({
    role: DataTypes.STRING,
    roleInfo: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Role',
  });
  return Role;
};
```

**Here is my User Model** **Model Schema**

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // role assoiation
      this.belongsTo(models.Role, {
        as: "role",
        foreignKey: "roleId",
      });
      // list assoiation
      this.hasMany(models.List, {
        as: "lists",
        foreignKey: "userId",
        onDelete: "CASCADE",
      });
    }
  };
  User.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      avatar: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },

      phoneNumber: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },

      address: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },

      website: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },

      bio: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      },

      fbUrl: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      twtUrl: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      linkUrl: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      insUrl: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
      },
      roleId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "User",
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

This is my Query

```
const user = await User.findOne({
        attributes: {
          exclude: ["password"],
        },
        where: { id: userId },
        include: [{ all: true, required: true }],
        // include: [{ model: Role }],
      });
```

Comment: What error or incorrect result do you have? Please show it in the post

Comment: I want to include Role tabel with the user table as json data , currently only RoleId is showing in user response but not full Role-Data, that is the question ,how can i include the role tabel as well.. please guide me...

Comment: Using `include`  of course. Can you show the result of `findOne` with `include: [{ model: Role }]`?